# Table formatting to split cells in 4

Tags: tables, formatting

I would like to split the numbers in the bottom two rows into different, equal sized columns, rather than separation by commas. My efforts so far have left me with a terrible looking table. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
\begin{table*}[]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | } 
\hline
   & AC rGO & RTA rGO & AC & GG & LiCoO$_2$ & FC \\
\hline
Voltage Range (V) & 0 $\to$ 3.5 & 0 $\to$ 3.5 & 0 $\to$ 3.5 & 0.01 $\to$ 1 &3.5 $\to$ 4.3 & 3 $\to$ 4.3 \\ 
 \hline
 C-Rates (Ag$^{-1}$) & 0.5, 1 ,5 , 10 & 0.5, 1, 5, 10  & 0.5, 1, 5, 10 & 0.5, 1, 2, 0.5& 0.2, 0.5 &0.5, 1, 2, 0.5    \\
  \hline
 Cycle Counts & 10, 10, 10, 10& 10, 10, 10, 10  & 10, 10, 10, 10 & 2, 10, 10, 5  & 2, 10  & 2, 10, 10, 5   \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
 \caption{}
 \label{}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please do not post such fragments only. Most likely you need some `\multicolumn approach, but this would mean a load of columns at all

Answer (score 5):

Something like this? The code uses a `tabualarx` environment with 18 centered `X` columns. By using a `tabularx` environment (along with a `\small` font-size directive, it's possible to set the table's width to `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{4}{c|}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | c | *{4}{*{4}{C}|} cc| *{4}{C} | } 
\hline
   & \mc{AC rGO} & \mc{RTA rGO} & \mc{AC} & \mc{GG} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{LiCoO$_2$} & \mc{FC} \\
\hline
Voltage Range (V) & \mc{0$\to$3.5} & \mc{0$\to$3.5} & \mc{0$\to$3.5} & \mc{0.01$\to$1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3.5$\to$4.3} & \mc{3$\to$4.3} \\ 
 \hline
 C-Rates (Ag$^{-1}$) & 0.5& 1 &5 & 10 & 0.5& 1& 5& 10  & 0.5& 1& 5& 10 & 0.5& 1& 2& 0.5& 0.2& 0.5 &0.5& 1& 2& 0.5    \\
\hline
 Cycle Counts & 10& 10& 10& 10& 10& 10& 10& 10  & 10& 10& 10& 10 & 2& 10& 10& 5  & 2& 10  & 2& 10& 10& 5   \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you bet me for few seconds ... in my very similar answer I spent a time to transcript `\mc{0$\to$3.5}` to my opinion more correct `\mc{$0\to 3.5$}` ...

Comment: Use `\usepackage{mhchem}` and `\ce{LiCoO_2}` for the chemical formula ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (btw really bad table design):

[image: bad]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,a4paper,margin=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} | c | cccc | cccc | cccc | cccc | cccc | cc | @{}}
    \hline
       & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{AC rGO} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{RTA rGO} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{AC} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{GG} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{LiCoO$_2$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{FC} \\
    \hline
    Voltage Range (V) & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{0 $\to$ 3.5} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{0 $\to$ 3.5} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{0 $\to$ 3.5} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{0.01 $\to$ 1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{3.5 $\to$ 4.3} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3 $\to$ 4.3}\\\hline
     C-Rates (Ag$^{-1}$) & 0.5 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 0.5 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 0.5 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 0.5 & 1 & 2 & 0.5 & 0.2 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 1 & 2 & 0.5\\\hline
     Cycle Counts & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 2 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 2 & 10 & 2 & 10 & 10 & 5\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test}\label{}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's the next-last group of columns that should have just two, rather than four, columns.

Comment: @Mico Probably you're right, but the OP will know this and change it. It's just an explanation how to do it.